# Why page break when inserting pictures?

Tags: diagrams

If I insert an image, then it is shown at the next page. Why do Latex a page break?

My code is:

```
 1208. \\ 
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=100mm]{Komplexa_talplanet.png}
\end{figure}\\
\\.
```

Comment: Perhaps it's at the bottom of the page. You need to give at least _some_ clues, preferably a complete small document that shows the problem. The `\\ ` are almost certainly not helping.

Comment: Note `figure` is a _floating_ environment, it's main purpose is to allow the system to move the figure, usually to the top of this or the next page.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to force the picture to be printed where you want, you might be looking for the `float` package. It provides the new option `H` to the figure placement which prevents the picture to be moved elsewhere.

```
\documentclass{article}% or whatever
\usepackage{float}% provides the H option to figure environment
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]% Specify the H option to force the placement exactly where figure enviromnent is called
\includegraphics[width=100mm]{Komplexa_talplanet.png}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: why use `[H]` why not simply remove `figure' ?

Comment: I guess for instance if you want to add a caption then the `figure` environment is needed. Anyway, this is the solution I personally have been using so far.

Comment: I wish I had never implemented `[H]` :-)

Comment: Note that the `[H]` location directive does not (and cannot) guarantee that the float will be on the same page as the immediately preceding material; if there's not enough space left on the current page, the float will have to be placed on the following page.

Comment: My opinion is that if an illustration doesn't need a caption, it shouldn't be placed in a `figure` environment, but probably inside `center`. If it requires a caption, then leave it float.